# Lazy loading with a result from the hydration cache

Tags: doctrine-orm

```
$queryBuilder = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
    ->from('ShopHqCartBundle:PromotionalDiscount', 'pd')
    ->leftJoin('pd.requiredSkus', 'pdrs')
    ->andWhere('pd.id = :id')
    ->select('pd', 'pdrs');
$query = $queryBuilder->getQuery();

$cache = $this->getEntityManager()->getConfiguration()->getResultCacheImpl();
$hydrationCacheProfile = new QueryCacheProfile(60 * 60 * 12, $cacheKeyHydrated, $cache);

$result = $query
  ->useQueryCache(true)
  ->useResultCache(true, 60 * 60 * 12, $cacheKey)
  ->setHydrationCacheProfile($hydrationCacheProfile)
  ->getResult();
```

The first time this runs I get back a managed entity and I can lazy load other relations. When getting a result back from the hydration cache it is not a managed entity and therefore lazy loading doesn't work. Is there something I can do to keep the hydration cache and get lazy loading to work with a result from the hydration cache?

Comment: @user2268997 unfortunately I couldn't find a solution to that problem. It is frustrating that it's not supported.